# make mouse recorder stop recording gui clicks

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput

I am building a program in python that has a tkinter Gui. On that GUI I have a button that allows me to start recording mouse clicks. And when I record mouse clicks I would like my program to ignore those clicks that are within my Gui so I can add special alterations to my recording like pixel recognition without adding more clicks. If I could check whether the page has been clicked before the program records the event that would help immensely.

```
selected=self.getScreenstate()
    if self.isRecording:
        if pressed:

            if self.up:
                self.up = False

                if selected==None:
                    pnt = [int(x), int(y)]
                    self.addToRecord(0,pnt,'')
```

Comment: You can add a check to your function to see if the mouse is located within a container in your GUI and if it is then do nothing and if not then finish record.

Comment: I kind of did that though the problem is when the page is behind another page or minimized it will think i am clicking the page unless what you are saying is different

Comment: px,py,width,height=self.getScreenstate()
        if self.isRecording:
            if pressed:

                if self.up:
                    self.up = False
                    if not (x>px and x<px+width and y>py and y<py+height+30):
                        pnt = [int(x), int(y)]
                        self.addToRecord(0,pnt,'')

            else:
                self.up = True

Comment: Ok in that case then maybe do a check that looks to see if you are active on the window where you can record clicks and if not don't do anything.

Comment: i had it check focus for some reson first time i click the page it still records posibly becaus it needs time to reolise it is selected

Comment: At this point I would need to see some basic code example to provide feedback on the issue. Please try to make a Minimum code example and add it to your question.

Comment: it i think i got it to work now because i added a delay after clicking befor i check if the screen is in focus